# some devices frequently not connecting to Belkin N450DB Wireless Router

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

I have 7 devices connected to my router.  1 desktop hardwired and 6 wireless devices: 2 windows 8 laptops, 1 windows phone, 1 wireless printer, and 1 Ipad. The problem is some of the wireless devices (usually the Ipad or the HP printer) frequently won't connect unless I restart the router.  IP address pool goes from 2 to 99, lease time: forever.

Any ideas of what I might try to fix this?  Not a ton of info to go on I know, but let me know if there's any details I can provide.

Comment: Why don't you just change the address pool back to 99 when it changes?  Sounds like the router is actually crashing, and restoring a default configuration, without your knowlege.  8 wireless devices on the router you describe is pushing its limits.

Comment: @Ramhound I'm not following you - the IP pool never changes.

Comment: You said it changes: "unless I restart the router. IP address pool goes from 2 to 99, lease time: forever."